# How can I set OSX to use local time instead of UTC?

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, macos-highsierra

I want OSX to use local time instead of UTC/GMT. I like my hardware clock to be set to local time.

In linux, it would be

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

Is there an osx equivalent to this command? I am running high sierra 10.3.6

Comment: Most of us set our time zone by clicking on the right time zone on the map during the first-boot setup assistant, and adjust it later if necessary in the Date & Time panel in System Preferences. Did you specifically need a command-line way to change it?

Comment: You may also find https://apple.stackexchange.com/ helpful.

Comment: @Spiff I don't have a problem with the time on OSX. What I want is for it to not set my hardware clock to UTC. It's a different thing from setting the local time in OSX, which is easy. What linux and osx do is set the hardware clock to utc and offset the OS time based on your timezone.